# UI with flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

[image]

I have a task design on figma, I want to create a widget the same as same with flutter.

I don't a ideal. Please help me. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not 100% accurate but here is what i got[image]

I use code from: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/draw-a-circular-control-with-custompainter-in-flutter-895cc3da0878

Create your background same

[image]

Here is my code:

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProgressIndicatorApp2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProgressIndicatorApp2({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: ProgressIndicatorExample(),
    );
  }
}

class ProgressIndicatorExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProgressIndicatorExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<ProgressIndicatorExample> createState() =>
      _ProgressIndicatorExampleState();
}

class _ProgressIndicatorExampleState extends State<ProgressIndicatorExample>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Container(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              width: 356,
              height: 523,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      image: AssetImage("assets/images/bgr_progress.png"))),
            ),
            Positioned(
                top: 55,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                child: Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: 240,
                      height: 240,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                              spreadRadius: 5,
                              blurRadius: 7,
                              offset:
                                  Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                            ),
                          ]),
                    ),
                    SemiCircleWidget(
                      diameter: 180,
                      sweepAngle: ((80 - 15) * 12.0).clamp(0.0, 180.0),
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 200,
                      height: 200,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                              spreadRadius: 5,
                              blurRadius: 7,
                              offset:
                                  Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                            ),
                          ]),
                    ),
                    const Text(
                      '50 %',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 60, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                    )
                  ],
                ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}

class SemiCircleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final double? diameter;
  final double? sweepAngle;
  final Color? color;

  const SemiCircleWidget({
    Key? key,
    this.diameter = 200,
    @required this.sweepAngle,
    @required this.color,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      painter: MyPainter(sweepAngle, color),
      size: Size(diameter!, diameter!),
    );
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  MyPainter(this.sweepAngle, this.color);

  final double? sweepAngle;
  final Color? color;
  double pi = 3.1415926535897932;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final Paint paint = Paint()
      ..strokeWidth = 60.0 // 1.
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke // 2.
      ..color = color!; // 3.

    double degToRad(double deg) => deg * (pi / 180.0);

    final path = Path()
      ..arcTo(
          // 4.
          Rect.fromCenter(
            center: Offset(size.height / 2, size.width / 2),
            height: size.height,
            width: size.width,
          ), // 5.
          degToRad(180), // 6.
          degToRad(sweepAngle!), // 7.
          false);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint); // 8.
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Note: You can update your paint to get exactly what you want